# Matlab Large ASCII Data with textscan resulting in multi-giga byte variable

Tags: matlab

I have several test data files in ASCII whose size varies from 100 MB to 600 MB. Two problems (or it could be one masking the other):

1. It seems, based on my research, that textscan hogs the physical memory.  My computer has been completely frozen up if I tried to load any file more than 200 MB (I have 16 GB physical memory in my PC)
2. I found out today once I successfully avoided freezing up the PC and loaded 190 MB data file, when I `whos`-ed an imported variable, it says that variable size is 7.4 GB. In fact, even after the importing was finished, the physical memory continued to stay at its 90%, near freezing point.

I tried the following:

```
data = struct;
count = 0;
while ~feof(fid)
    count = count+1;
    data_temp = textscan(fid, format, 100000, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true,...
        'EmptyValue' ,NaN, 'ReturnOnError', false);
   data(count).blocks = data_temp;
   clear data_temp
end
```

But it doesn't seem to help (played with the number of lines as well). I tried a similar method without a structure, but just relying on the `textscan` pointer. Not much difference.

Comment: Is your data truly 100000 columns wide? And if it's not, is the output of `textscan` with that number of column repetitions always that size? That could explain the large memory requirement. Also take a look at [this link about tall arrays](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html). The latest MATLAB version (R2016b) can handle billions of rows of data, which might just be what you need.

Comment: Oh, great.  I have 2016b although for graphics reasons, 2015b is my default.  I will give that a shot.  I thought the number of lines meant for the rows.  The maximum column length I've come across was a few thousands and rows can be maybe a million or so.  But like I said, I played with that number as low as 50 up to the number shown above, it didn't make much difference.

Comment: Use the [datastore](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.html) (introduced in R2014b) or the [tabularTextDatastore](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tabulartextdatastore.html) (introduced in R2016a) to work with the files without actually loading all data at once (which won't fit in memory). These data stores only load those parts you need, or load the files in chunks that fit in memory to perform calculations on all the data. Let us know if this is what you're looking for and if it works for your data!